# Teamcity agents not fully using computer resources

Tags: visual-studio-2010, teamcity

My Visual Studio 2010 solution builds very slow on Teamcity, it ranges from 2 to 10 times slower in Teamcity than building in VS2010 from IDE.

I noticed my CPU usage when Teamcity is building is less than 30% while running VS is close to 100%. I guess the this accounts for the slow build speed but I don't understand why Teamcity is doing this.

I am using Teamcity 7.13 but have tested on 8.13 and got the same result.

Comment: Perhaps compilation is not cpu-bound? If there's many files, it could be disk-bound.

Comment: Does your dev machine have an SSD? Does your build server? I suspect that is where the differences is

Comment: I have thought about it but the disk usage in Resource Monitor does not really stand out. The VS test is done by logging into the build server machine, so the machine spec for both sets of test are exactly the same.

Comment: Make sure you use the `/m` parameter for parallel MSBuild building, that *could* be the issue - it's hard to tell without knowing more about your VM specs and your solution/projects

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue earlier today and I sped up my Build Process drastically, by around 30% by adding a CommandLine Parameter of "/MaxCpuCount" to my TeamCity MSBuild step.

By specifying "/MaxCpuCount", will cause MSBuild to automatically spin up an MSBuild process per Processor and will allow projects to be built concurrently (Where they can be) across all of these processes. If you wish you can manually specify the MaxCpuCount eg "/MaxCpuCount:4" will start 4 MSBuild processes. You can read more on MaxCpuCount at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651793.aspx

Another tip for speeding up your MSBuild process is to use HardLinks too. For more information on HardLinks, see here http://atombrenner.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/speed-up-your-build-with.html

I implemented all options for CreateHardLinks in my BuildProcess along with MaxCpuCount and sped up my process 67% from 8 minutes to 3 minutes.

As mentioned already you could also be restricted by Disk IO so that also might be worth looking into, but the above should also help you out a bit.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried the MaxCpu trick and that didn't seem to help.  I am still only using about 3% CPU for the builds which take a very long time.  Any other ideas? Tnx!